# UIViewAnimation behaves inconsistently iOS

Tags: ios, ios7.1

I've got a UIViewAnimation that behaves inconsistently.  Once it starts, there are two different controllers I can navigate to.  When I go to to the "left" controller - and back again, the animation starts over.  There is a 2 second delay then a fade up.  All good there.  When I go to the "right" controller - and back again, the graphic I am animating is already there.  It just "pops" on - as if it's ignoring the delay and fade in I specified.

Here is the code:

```
 if ([DefaultHandler getFirstContact]){

    [firstUseArrow setAlpha:0];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [firstUseArrow setAlpha:.8];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:4 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [firstUseArrow setAlpha:0];
        } completion:nil];
    }];


}else{
    firstUseArrow.alpha = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi rmaddy.  Thank you for fixing my tags.  By any chance could you share my error so I can avoid next time?  :)